# Matching values from two queries into the same table

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, html-table

I'm trying to add a description to a coded value on PHP. The code was extracted from a table, and the description from another. The idea is that they are presented on a table with the proper description for each code, but when I tried to add the raw ordered query, the descriptions where misplaced, so I tried this:

```
 <table>
 for($i=0; $i < $items; $i++)
 {
     $row = $results -> fetch_array();
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>'.$row['code'].'</td>';
     for($j=0; $j<$items2; $j++) 
     {
         $row2 = $result2 -> fetch_array();
         if ($row['code'] == $row2['code']) 
         {
             echo '<td>'.$row2['description'].'</td>';
         }
     }
     echo '</tr>';
 }
 echo '</table>';
```

It's working for the first value, but only that one, the rest of the column is empty.

Comment: Sidenote: `<items2` unless that is a constant, it should read as `<$items2`. Stack's syntax highlighter shows there's an error, along with `<table>
 for($i=0; $i < $items; $i++)` with no opening/closing php tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is, that you have to reset the row pointer for `$result2`.

```
 <table>
 for($i=0; $i < $items; $i++)
 {
     $row = $results -> fetch_array();
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>'.$row['code'].'</td>';
     for($j=0; $j<items2; $j++) 
     {
         $result2 -> data_seek( 0 );
         $row2 = $result2 -> fetch_array();
         if ($row['code'] == $row2['code']) 
         {
             echo '<td>'.$row2['code'].'</td>';
         }
     }
     echo '</tr>';
 }
 echo '</table>';
```

Every time you call `fetch_array`, an internal row pointer is incremented by one. So in the outer for loop´s second cycle, `$result2 -> fetch_array()` will retun `NULL` since there is no more result left.

Alternatively, you can iterate through `$result2` before the first loop und store the results in a two dimensional array. However: I would prefer to use a `JOIN` to put together the two statements, so that you only will get one resultset. But there´s too few information provided, to see if that´s possible in this case.

[MySQL JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: Adding the data_seek(0) inside the second loop gave some weird results, but when I tryied it inside the first one it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Hum ... what is the link between the loop ($j) and the row2 ? $j is not used ? Should not be a parameter of your query ?

I think what you need is something like this:

```
<?php
$data1 = $results->fetch_array();
$data2 = $results2->fetch_array();

foreach( $data1 as $row ) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>', $row['code'], '</td>';
  foreach( $data2 as $row2 ) {
    echo '<td>';
    if( $row['code'] == $row2['code'] ) {
      echo 'match';
    }
    else {
      echo 'no match';
    }
    echo '</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

I didn't added the for because I didn't understand what you want.
For your fetch_array, you can call it only one time (if you change a parameter, i.e.: somefield=$j), there is another logic).